# SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services mode

Tags: sql-server

How do you find out if a SQL Server 2012 installation has Analysis Services Tabular Mode or Multidimensional Mode installed?

Answer (score 2):

Barely worth an answer, but [Determine the Server Mode of an Analysis Services Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471594.aspx) includes:

> - Server Icons in Object Explorer
>
>   The easiest way to determine server mode is to connect to the server in SQL Server Management Studio and note the icon next to the server name in Object Explorer. The following illustration shows three instances of Analysis Services deployed in Multidimensional, Tabular, and PowerPivot modes

[image]

> - Viewing DeploymentMode Property in MSMDSRV.INI File
>
>   Alternatively, you can check the DeploymentMode property in the msmdsrv.ini file that is included in every Analysis Services instance. The value of this property identifies the server mode. Valid values are 0 (Multidimensional), 1 (SharePoint), or 2 (Tabular).

Answer (score 1):

```
# the script is run on a host where SSAS 2012 installed
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Culture=Neutral, Version=11.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";

$s=new-object "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server";
$s.connect( '<your_SSAS_instance>' );
$s.ServerMode
```

Answer (score 0):

You have theses two details :

1 Select `Analysis Services from the Feature Tree in Setup`. Optionally, choose SQL Server Data Tools to include the tabular model designer in your installation.
[image]

2 On the `Analysis Services Configuration page`, be sure to select `Tabular Mode`.

[image]

Comment: I know how to do this from install, but I am using a virtual machine with SQL Server already installed and I need to know what mode Analysis Services is set to.

Comment: you access analysis services configuration (second part of answer)